# Django - querying all models that have common fields

Tags: django, django-queryset

If I have many Django models - all with the following common fields: -

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and I would like to query all models to find out which objects were created or modified by a specific user, is there a sane way to go about achieving this?

Or do I have to fall back to doing `ModelA.objects.filter(created_by=userone)` `ModelB.objects.filter(created_by=userone)` and so on?

I should mention that in reality these fields are in an abstract base class from which all other models inherit them. But let's pretend I didn't tell you what I just told you about the abstract base class, is there still a way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to operate on one model at a time. Djano ORM managers internally make use of a class called `Queyset` which talks with database and this class `QuerySet` instances have a `model` attribute on them which is synonymous to a single table. So, they can only talk with one table, though join operations are possible. But for your scenario you will have to make multiple calls to db.

orm is just an abstraction over database, think if you can do this directly with sql.

At sql:

```
select val from test union select val from test2 union......;
```

So there will be a lot of unions since you say you have a lot of models so doesn't make much sense to accomplish this with a single db call.

Comment: That's true there are many models that I'm dealing with here. Looking for an efficient way to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

to expand on what akshar raaj is saying, you can simplify the code by having an array of models.

```
query_models = [ModelA, ModelB, ModelC, ModelD]
for query_model in query_models:
    results = query_model.objects.filter(created_by=userone)
    if len(results) > 0:
        print '%s has it!!!' % query_model.__name__
```

Comment: That's a good pointer. That's probably how I'll proceed if I there isn't a more efficient way of achieving this.